# Is It Possible To Use Javascript/CSS To Swap Style Sheets When A Mobile Device Rotates?

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, android

I am working on a site that must be designed with mobile accessibility in mind.  As part of our brainstorming, we wondered whether it's possible to detect, for a mobile browser (i.e. Mobile Safari or the Android browser), when the viewing device has changed orientation, and to use that as a trigger to change page content?  As the title of this question implies, our best-case scenario is the ability to detect the orientation change and use it to alter the CSS on the fly so as to present a slightly different page for landscape versus portrait.

Of course we can just design for a page that looks good one way and make it obvious that it's supposed to be viewed that way, but the cool-stuff factor of a page that looks good either way is pretty appealing.

Is this idea implementable?  Practical?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is answered in a [more general question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086)

To summarize, you would listen with Javascript to the `orientationchange` event, and switch the styling in the event handler, depending on the value of `window.orientation`.

Comment: Well, drat.  I missed that question during my initial SO search for answers to this question.  Starred now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use media queries to do this without any JS at all - see http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/dealing-with-device-orientation

Answer (score 0):

Make a fluid style that would adjust in any case..

You would have to give a more detailed description of issues you want to solve so we can suggest more detailed answers..