# Prevent Safari/iPad to go in landscape mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, mobile-safari

I have a website for iPad and I want visitors to see it in portrait only.
Is it possible to prevent Safari/iPad to go in landscape mode?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Cheers,
Robert

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent orientation change in iOS Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298467/prevent-orientation-change-in-ios-safari)

Comment: First detect it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495678/how-to-find-out-if-ipad-is-in-landscape-portrait-mode-in-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not possible to prevent this. It’s a browser feature, and this cannot be controlled using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone says you can't do this, but you can hackity hack it. I do not advise unless you really have to, but you could use js to detect orientation change, and upon that change use css3 to rotate a full wrapper div 90 degrees ( transform: rotate )