# Android detect rotation & screen width

Tags: android, webkit, rotation, landscape, portrait

I am trying to detect screen rotation in Webkit on my Motorola Droid 1.  I have the following JavasCript code:

```
var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window,
    orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? "orientationchange" : "resize";

window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
    alert("screen.width: " + screen.width + ", window.orientation: " + window.orientation);
}, false);
```

The problem is: it alerts screen.width 569 when the phone is rotated in portrait, and 320 when it is rotated in landscape.  This does not any sense to me!  Can somebody clarify?

Thank you,
Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you are running Android 2.2.  There is a bug in the browser's reporting of width and height.  See [screen.width + android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021090/screen-width-android) and [Shouldn't window.screen.width/height correspond to actual screen width/height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702073/shouldnt-window-screen-width-height-correspond-to-actual-screen-width-height) for starters.

I wish I had something better to offer than the `setTimeout()` workaround in that first post, but that may be the best you can do.  (I'd love to be wrong about that, so if someone knows a better solution, please share!)