# incorrect values using screen.width/screen.height

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 4k monitor 3840x2160 but
when I use screen.width I get 1920 instead 3840
when I use screen.height I get 1080 instead 2160
why values are incorrect
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHHhG.png)

Comment: Hi, as you are using `200%` scaling that's why its half of the original width and height.

Comment: Thanks, but I hope I should use 4k images to my 4k screen, so can I get real screen width or there are another method to pick up an image resolution to screen...? image{width: 100vw; height :100vh}

Answer (score 3):

There is a similar question with the same problem you can check it from this link:

[Shouldn't window.screen.width/height correspond to actual screen width/height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702073/shouldnt-window-screen-width-height-correspond-to-actual-screen-width-height)

Note: I am on mobile idk how to format the answer