# flash.sensors.Accelerometer on Android within web browser

Tags: android, flash, sensors, android-2.2-froyo

The Accelerometer `UPDATE` event never fires, tho `isSupported` returns true, when the flash app is running inside the android web browser. **How can I make it work?**

```
     this.accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
            accelerometer.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, onAccelerometerUpdate);
```

Ref: http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/04/simple_accelerometer_example.html

Ref: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/sensors/Accelerometer.html#isSupported

My device is Samsung Galaxy S.

It does however work as an AIR app on android.

Ref: ["Adobe Forums - Accelerometer"](http://forums.adobe.com/search.jspa?resultTypes=DOCUMENT&resultTypes=MESSAGE&resultTypes=COMMUNITY&resultTypes=TASK&resultTypes=PROJECT&resultTypes=SOCIAL_GROUP&resultTypes=COMMENT&peopleEnabled=true&q=Accelerometer)

Comment: Raise the issue with Adobe. It could be a bug. It works on my NExus One

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You declared accelerometer as a local variable, so once it is out of scope it will no longer exist. Declaring the var as a class instance member ensures its existence until you no longer need it. http://forums.adobe.com/message/3363673#3363673

The fix was to declare the Accelerometer instance as a class member instead of a local variable.