# How to check if the user is shaking mobile device in chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, mobile

Is there a way to check if the user is shaking his/her mobile device using only html5 (no Javascript) in a web-app?

Edit: Sorry for adding Javascript in the question. I want to know if it's possible only by HTML5?

Comment: Related: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474508/access-accelerometer-via-javascript-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474508/access-accelerometer-via-javascript-in-android)

Comment: @royhowie I have to disagree with the duplicate vote here - that question asks how to get accelerometer data, whereas this question asks specifically how to use accelerometer data to determine when the user is shaking the device.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister So do I.

Comment: Duplicate? Please give the link if it's duplicate and please read the edited question.

Comment: To answer your edited question, accelerometer data cannot be accessed via HTML alone, only through JavaScript. If you cannot accept a solution that uses JavaScript, then unfortunately there is no solution to your problem.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Still, there is a difference between "how to detect a shake" and "how to access the accelerometer data".