# Is it possible to launch mobile sensor with html5 but only with android webview?

Tags: html, webview, android-webview

I mean without cordova or other framework. I'm pretty sure i need to write Java code and link it somehow with html5 through the android webview.
If it is possible, can get a little example how to connect to the camera or other sensor.

Comment: Could you please look into below article.It might help u. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474508/access-accelerometer-via-javascript-in-android

Comment: What are your "red lines", if you already accept to do it android java, and output in a webview, then there is no problem, simple. Launch, well that's different (I assume you know what the virtual machine, and a sandbox is)[and why they are there], seems arbitrary. You should update your tags, add android at least.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the sensors have a JavaScript API such as [geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation), [orientation (gyroscope)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation) and the [battery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API). To access the camera you could use `MediaDevices.getUserMedia`, however, this is still in an experimental stage and is not supported by all Android devices. For more information refer to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia).

Answer (score 0):

Look into JavascriptInterface

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Specifically, addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String))

```
@JavascriptInterface
class JsInterface {
  public void startCamera() { ... }
}

WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(), "androidInterface");
```

Basically, add the JavascriptInterface, and enable javascript on the web view.  Then in your javascript you can detect if the interface exists like so:

```
if ("undefined" != typeof androidInterface) {
    androidInterface.startCamera();
}
```

Now in the Java code for startCamera, you can do whatever native stuff you need done.