# Navigating forms using layouts in multiple layout orientations?

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

I have a project with a number of forms. 
I use Layouts on all my forms.

Each form has essentially the same code (see below) for when I am navigating between them.

```
Application.GotoForm('frmInventory', feFromRight);
```

Everything is great until I change orientations (e.g. from profile to landscape). 
Then the Layouts get screwed up.

> see [screenshot1](https://s24.postimg.org/fqs6u9g91/screenshot1.png)  versus [screenshot2](https://s24.postimg.org/r06kpnlj9/screenshot2.png).

Example Code:

```
procedure TfrmMenu.frmMenuDeactivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 fLayout:= nil;
end;


procedure TfrmMenu.frmMenuActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 fLayout:= Layout.Client([Layout.Top(fHeader),
                           Layout.Bottom(fFooter),
                           Layout.Client(fList)]);
end;


procedure TfrmMenu.Resize;
begin
  inherited;
   if assigned(FLayout) then
   begin
    fLayout.Resize(self)
   end;
end;
```

That is correct!  Why isn't it. What am i missing? How do you capture the orientation change?

----- UPDATE -----

Searching on this site, I cam across this article:

http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2012/02/detecting-device-movement.html

which then led me to this stackoverflow answer:

[Access accelerometer via Javascript in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474508/access-accelerometer-via-javascript-in-android)

```
 if (window.DeviceMotionEvent == undefined) {
        //No accelerometer is present. Use buttons. 
        alert("no accelerometer");
    }
    else {
        alert("accelerometer found");
        window.addEventListener("devicemotion", accelerometerUpdate, true);
    }
```

in SMS, this seems to do it:

```
function window: variant; external 'window' property;

procedure TfrmItem.InitializeObject;
begin
  inherited;
  {$I 'Item:impl'}
  window.addEventListener('devicemotion', @Resize, false);
  .
  .
  .
end;

procedure TfrmItem.Resize;
begin
  inherited;
  if assigned(fLayout) then
  begin
    fLayout.Resize(self);
    ResizeControls;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Great tip! You should add your finding as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching on this site, I cam across this article:

http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2012/02/detecting-device-movement.html

which then led me to this stackoverflow answer:

Access accelerometer via Javascript in Android?

```
 if (window.DeviceMotionEvent == undefined) {
        //No accelerometer is present. Use buttons. 
        alert("no accelerometer");
    }
    else {
        alert("accelerometer found");
        window.addEventListener("devicemotion", accelerometerUpdate, true);
    }
```

in SMS, this seems to do it:

```
function window: variant; external 'window' property;

procedure TfrmItem.InitializeObject;
begin
  inherited;
  {$I 'Item:impl'}
  window.addEventListener('devicemotion', @Resize, false);
  .
  .
  .
end;

procedure TfrmItem.Resize;
begin
  inherited;
  if assigned(fLayout) then
  begin
    fLayout.Resize(self);
    ResizeControls;
  end;
end;
```