# screen.width + android

Tags: javascript, android, width, screen

If I trace out the screen.width with my DroidX native browser, I first receive 320 as expected, but on subsequent reloads (without changing orientation) I receive 800... why is this?

Comment: What do you mean by "trace out"?

Comment: Can no one confirm this?  Is it a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an Android bug. Sometimes when page first loads the window.screen.width and window.screen.height are wrong. You can try to make a timeout and then run your code.

```
setTimeout(YourFunction, 200);
```

Also see here [android issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12455&q=javascript%20width&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Comment: should this be done before or after onload of the page, or is it going to work either way?

Comment: I've found that using window.outerHeight works; screen.height is broken indeed.

Comment: It is almost 7 years since the answer was posted. Is the bug still fixed?