# Delaying javascript code execution in called function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this class that has methods that capture some specific information. One very important method is `getViewportWidth`.

Due to a bug/feature in Android 2.2 or so, the widths that are reported are not quite accurate for users using this device platform (You can see more about this here: [How do I find the virtual viewport/screen width using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677794/how-do-i-find-the-virtual-viewport-screen-width-using-javascript)

The workaround seems to be to delay script execution of the whole script. However, because I need to take care of this transparent from the user, I want to instead delay script execution at the function level i.e. at my `getViewportWidth` function.

So that a user can just call:

`MyClass.getViewportWidth();`

And the delay would have been taken care of.

So basically, I'm trying to find a way to delay code execution in my `getViewportWidth` function by 200 milliseconds to accomodate this bug/feature. How can I do this?!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout` to delay the execution of a function by some milliseconds. Use like:

```
var text = "Hi!";
setTimeout(function () {
    alert(text);
}, 200); // 200 ms
```