# Trigger Jquery with media screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a small website and I am using both jquery-mobile and my custom jquery functions in a separate file.

I want the jquery mobile to be triggered only by devices with less than 760px and my custom jquery to function above 760px. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the virtual viewport/screen width using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677794/how-do-i-find-the-virtual-viewport-screen-width-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code in a conditional statement using the `.innerWidth()` jQuery method. Note that this method cannot be applied to `$(document)` or `$(window)`, for those you may consider the `.width()` instead. checkout "http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/" for more details.

Example:

```
if($("body").innerWidth() < "760px") {
//enter jQuery code here
}
```

Also note that, the `.innerWidth()` method gets the dimensions of the selected element including the padding and content but excluding borders and margins.