# Mobile Website Redirect issue?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

i am trying to use this code to redirect to a mobile website, but when i go to my site on my phone, it does not redirect. What is the problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if (screen.width <= 800 && document.referrer.indexOf('http://m.codtelevision.com') != 0) {
    window.location = "http://m.codtelevision.com";
}

</script>
```

Also, i need the code so if i am on my mobile site, and click Full site, it does not redirect back to the mobile site.

Answer (score 1):

Mobiles usually have little or no java script support you need to check for the user-agent in your server side script and redirect your user to mobile version from server rather then doing it in javascript.

Comment: how do i do that if there is not javascript?

Comment: In ASP.NET you can use mobile.browser and redirect directly in php you can check for $_REQUEST["User-Agent"] and if it contains string like "*nokia*" or "*mobile*" you can redirect via header("Location : mobile.yourweb.com") ;

Comment: i have found this link...http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ ... but i need something i can go to the full site and it not redirect back to the mobile site

Comment: can you see my question above this message?

Comment: What server side script you're using ? you can't do it in plain html

Comment: well, i did download the php script the uploaded it, but got nothing...now i am trying the javascript...but i like the script i had originally, is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.location.href = "http://m.codtelevision.com";
```

<strike>I'm pretty sure the document.referrer thing solves your mobile site problem though I'd probably have used a session variable or cookie somewhere to indicate what type of site the user has chosen to view.</strike>

The answer to your latter question depends on what mobile browsers you are supporting and what sort of backend technologies you are using. With plain html/javascript a cookie might work.

Comment: my phone is still oading the full site

Comment: What mobile device are you using?

Comment: well the javascript we're using is pretty simple. start debugging. replace your javascript with document.write(screen.width) see what it spits out on your mobile.

Comment: Also, read this. http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021090/screen-width-android