# jquery / javascript - listen for change in window orientation mode on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if there's some sort of cross-device method of listening for orientation mode changes on mobile devices with jquery / javascript?

Comment: Are you using any specific javascript mobile framework like JQTouch or JQueryMobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question explains how to do it using plain javascript for iPhone and Android [Detect rotation of Android phone in the browser with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

[JQuerymobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) has an `orientationchange` event, check out their website for more info and demo's.

Comment: If I could figure out a way to implement just certain features of jquery mobile, that'd be great, but including their entire suite of features is a bit much.