# JS Mobile detect viewport orientation changes

Tags: javascript, mobile

What would be the best approach to detect whenever the user changes the orientation of his phone. I am talking for a mobile site not for a native app.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener('onorientationchange', function () {
    if (window.orientation == -90) {
        //do stuff
    }
    if (window.orientation == 90) {
        //do stuff
    }
    if (window.orientation == 0) {
        //do stuff
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, are they any browser or hardware issue with this methode ?

Comment: Actually just tested and its not working on android, is this ios only feature ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript