# What is the best global way to detect screen orientation on tablets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, orientation

I'm looking for a global solution which will detect orientation on tablets (not just iPad or Android device but the more the better).

One solution :

```
  device.portrait = function() {
    return (window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth) > 1;
  };

  device.landscape = function() {
    return (window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth) < 1;
  };
```

My point of view is that this above is not working well.

I need good solution to load dedicated images in carousel on portrait view and dedicated image on landscape view when orientation change.

Cheers.

Comment: Why is that code not working for you?

Answer (score 2):

Use media queries for that

For landscape

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { 
    /*css for a image*/ 
}
```

For portrait

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: portrait) { 
    /*css for different image*/
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify:

i have to dynamically change images in carousel so CSS won't solve my problem.

Comment: I will work good, css properties are applied to the elements, whether elements comes dynamically or anything else it will not harm.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your code is not working well .
But I can suggest you to use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13869089/1427849) which is works for me ,

```
<span id="orientation">orientation</span>​

$(document).ready(checkOrientation);
$(window).resize(checkOrientation);

function checkOrientation() {
    var orientation = "Portrait";
    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    var screenHeight = $(window).height();
    if (screenWidth > screenHeight) {
        orientation = "Landscape";
    }
    $("#orientation").html(orientation);
}​
```

And you can see [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jjc39/) !