# How can i change Screen Orientation using javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am developing a application using Phonegap for Android and iphone. I need to change the screen orientation when i am navigating from one page to another. Can any one tell how it can be done through either java script or  jquery ?

Thank you

Comment: I think you can't, since neither JavaScript nor jQuery (wrote in JavaScript) can do this as far as I know.

Comment: Do you mean "adapt my output to the current screen orientation", not "change the device's screen orientation"?

Comment: You know jQuery can't do anything that JavaScript can't do, right? (Because jQuery is "just" a JavaScript library.)

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();

    if (width > height) {
        // Landscape
        $("#mode").text("LANDSCAPE");
    } else {
        // Portrait
        $("#mode").text("PORTRAIT");
    }

});
```

Another one id `window.orientation` which return `0`, `90` or `-90` where:

- `0` stands for: portrait mode
- `90` stands for: landscape mode with the screen turned to the left
- `-90` stands for: landscape mode with the screen turned to the right

  ```
   window.onorientationchange = function() 
  {
  var orientation = window.orientation;
  switch(orientation) {
      case 0:
          //Top side up.
          break; 

      case -90:
          //Left side up (turned 90 degrees to the right)
          break;

      case 90: 
          //Right side up (turned 90 degrees to the left)
          break;
    }
  }
  ```

You can also see

[Detect rotation of Android phone in the browser with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript) for info.