# Prevent orientation change on rotation on all platforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to prevent the change of a websites orientation regardless of how a mobile device is rotated without having to write platform specific code? Under the circumstances the goal is to keep a site in "Portrait" mode.

Comment: Nope. Best you an do is plan your site for a "responsive layout" without something like [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).  A native client would give you more control, but in the JS world you can only detect when the size changes.

Comment: @SciSpear 'nuf said. You should post that as an answer. Preventing a handheld device from rotating the website simply goes beyond the limits of JavaScript.

Comment: @Derija93—it is possible with script (it's actually quite easy), but disabling orientation changes should only be done if there's an extremely good (usually very specific) reason.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Best you an do is plan your site for a "responsive layout" without something like [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). A native client would give you more control, but in the JS world you can only [detect when the size changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript).

Under the advice of @Derija93 I posted this as an answer so we can close this question.

EDIT:  Now that being said.  You might be able to fake it with [some css translations](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp) (you will see it jump around).. but I really would not recommend going down this path.