# Reload javascript on mobile-device rotation?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that calculates the height of a div and returns it as a style. But when you rotate mobile-devices the height changes, so I need a way to reload it. How can I accomplish this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var height = document.getElementById('id').offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById('id').style.marginTop = height + 'px';
}
</script>
```

Comment: I saw it described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2307936/944681) (at least for Android).

Comment: No need, just use window resize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a function out of it and call that on both load and resize.  No need to reload your page, just call the code again:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcHeight() {
    var height = document.getElementById('id').offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById('id').style.marginTop = height + 'px';
}

window.onload = calcHeight;
window.resize = calcHeight;

</script>
```

Comment: It works in cases like `alert("resize event detected!");` but not for my script. Why?

Comment: @nicolas - Perhaps you need to reset the marginTop back to it's default value (like it was when the page was loaded) before getting the offsetHeight.  There's probably a better way to do what you're trying to do, but without seeing the HTML, we can't advise on that.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function:

```
function setHeight() {
   var height = document.getElementById('id').offsetHeight;
   document.getElementById('id').style.marginTop = height + 'px';
}
```

That you can call onload:

```
window.onload = function() {
   setHeight();
   // Other actions when window is loaded
}
```

And onresize:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
   setHeight();
   // Other actions when window is resized
}
```

This should do the job.