# Detect if browser/device supports screen rotation

Tags: javascript, screen-rotation

Is there a way to detect if the browser/device supports screen rotation, without having to wait for the *orientationchange* event? I'm not trying to detect the rotation itself, only if the browser or device supports it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [**Detect rotation of Android phone in the browser with javascript**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can detect it like so:

```
if( 'onorientationchange' in window) { /* supported! */ }
```

However, I'm not sure if some browsers will support the event even though they never fire it.

Comment: For thoroughness it might be worth checking to see if it holds a value for `window.orientation` too, but if the browser lies about supporting/firing `onorientationchange` there's a good chance it'll present a complete 'lie' I guess.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. I guess this is the best possible solution, but it won't be triggered by some devices (according to this page: http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change)...

Answer (score 0):

You should assume that *all* devices can change their orientation because you can turn any screen to the other orientation using the OS. This is unless you [lock the orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/lock), which is **not** recommended in most cases.

Technically, `window.orientation` and `window.orientationchange` are deprecated. We should instead use the [`screen.orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation) object and `change` event listener.

However, Safari [does not yet support](https://caniuse.com/screen-orientation) screen orientation. So you should have both for now:

```
if (screen.orientation) {
  screen.orientation.addEventListener('change', handleOrientationChange);
} else {
  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', handleOrientationChange);
}
```

When the device is not rotated this listener will not fire. But it *could* fire for any device.

For more information, see ["Managing screen orientation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Managing_screen_orientation) in MDN's docs.