# Dropbox and Menu

Tags: jquery, css, html, menu

It may seem silly that I speak, but I am having difficulties with Jquery.
My goal is to apply. "Hide" on a menu and ". Mes" dropbox, and the dropbox will only appear when the screen is less than or equal to 320px (portrait smartphone).
The problem is when the phone is in portrait and in I change to Landscape (480px), the menu does not appear and does not hide the dropbox. keeps the dropbox.

I would do anything to alter independende the initial position of the screen.

JSFIDDLE(bugged, but works): http://jsfiddle.net/eJZSd/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var width = $(window).width();

    if(width<400){
          $("#Menu_Drop").show();
          $("aside").hide();
    }
    else{
          $("#Menu_Drop").hide();
          $("aside").show();
    }

    $('img').on('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: 'fade',
        slideshow: true,  
        touch: true,  
        keyboard: true,
        slideshowSpeed: 7000, 
        animationSpeed: 500,
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: false,  

        before: function(){

        $("#Mensagem").animate({ opacity: '0', });

        $(".triangulo").animate({ opacity: '1', });

        $(".triangulo").animate({ borderWidth: '0px', });

        },

        after: function(){
          if(width<500){
          $(".triangulo").animate({ borderWidth: '10px', });
        }
        else{
          $(".triangulo").animate({ borderWidth: '70px', });
        }


          $("#Mensagem").animate({ opacity: '1', });

        }, 


    });
  });
```

Comment: Insert the relevant code in your Question. The best questions out here have a short text and a simplified code where one can spot immediately the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the issue you are having is that you're not detecting when the "window" size changes due to the screen rotating.

According to [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6603537/191500), the trick is to add an event listener for either `resize` or `orientationchange`.  Then you would run your 400 check again.

Add this piece outside of your `$(document).ready(){...}` section

```
var previousOrientation = window.orientation;
var checkOrientation = function(){
    if(window.orientation !== previousOrientation){
        previousOrientation = window.orientation;

        // orientation changed, do your magic here
        var width = $(window).width();

        if(width<400){
              $("#Menu_Drop").show();
              $("aside").hide();
        }
        else{
              $("#Menu_Drop").hide();
              $("aside").show();
        }
    }
};
```

Then this piece inside of `$(document).ready(){...}`

```
window.addEventListener("resize", checkOrientation, false);
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", checkOrientation, false);
```

Comment: Don't work :/ I'll add the code on question.
CODE: [link](http://pastebin.com/VCH4zNCG)

Comment: Is deforming the entire site.

Comment: Hmm, you sure thats because of this particular piece of code?  Or could it be part of the flexslider, css or similar?  Probably worth commenting out parts until you can narrow down what in particular is breaking.