# Disable landscape screen orientation for mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, browser, responsive-design, landscape-portrait

I am developing a responsive website and its interface is not good for small height screens. I would like to know if it's possible to disable the landscape orientation on the mobile browsers screens. For example, if you access the website in landscape orientation, he would see it in portrait orientation.

I know that the mobile operating systems allow you to disable, but I would like to force it through the HTML or Javascript code.

Thanks!

Comment: You might find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript

Comment: @LuFaMa: He doesn't want to detect it, he wants to prevent it...

Comment: That's it, @Bergi! Do you know something about?