# Meta Viewport tags and Device Orientation

Tags: css, html

I've got this meta tag...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no">
```

My app is absolutely positioning at 0 0 0 0, and everything scrolls inside. I have two fixed bars, header and footer, so it's important that I include the content height.

Now consider that the user changes the device orientation. The height of the content is now the **width** of the device, but the meta tag doesn't change. So now my footer bar will not be visible.

What do?

Comment: Might have to reload the page. There are JS utilities that can help detect device rotation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually change the size through JavaScript on `orientationchange`. See [Mobile Safari device-width/height orientationchange bug](http://julio-ody.tumblr.com/post/38211623350/mobile-safari-device-width-height-orientationchange-bug) for details.

This is from the blog post:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() {
  document.querySelector('html').style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px'
}, false)
```

The link above also contains a jQuery version if that's your library of choice.