# Jquery mobile orientationChange error on startup in landscape mode

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, orientation-changes

I have some kind of app, where interface depends on orientation change. So I have two functions for interface `portraitSet()` and `landscapeSet()`. Here is the code how I catching up orientation change event:

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(event){
    alert(event.orientation);
        if (event.orientation == 'portrait')
        {
            $(portraitSet());
        }
        else if (event.orientation == 'landscape')
        {
            $(landscapeSet());
        }
});
```

On launch app in portrait mode it works perfectly, but when start app in landscape mode and  trying to set mobile into portrait mode my `alert(event.orientation)` giving me message "*landscape*", but mobile on portrait mode. Where is my mistake?

Comment: On start up `mobileinit` check height and width.

Answer (score 0):

hi use this code.....

```
$(window).resize( function(){
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();
        if(width>height) {
      // Landscape
          alert("LANDSCAPE");
        } else {
      // Portrait
        alert("PORTRAIT");
        }

       });
```

if you need more [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript)