# Meteor, detect device orientation change

Tags: meteor, meteor-cordova

I'm building an mobile app with Meteor. Now if the phone changes orientation, the page no longer renders correctly. So I need to refresh the page after orientation change.

Is there a way to detect the orientation change in Meteor cordova app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A good point to start is this post that actually covers both Android and iOS platforms:

[Detect rotation of Android phone in the browser with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript)

We currently have two handlers added with `window.addEventListener` in
`Template.template_name.created`. `resize` event is used on Android and `orientationchange` event is used on iOS.